# `TimeDistributed` Layer should be passed an `input_shape ` with at least 3 dimensions, received: [None, 400]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, conv-neural-network

I am trying to amalgamate the CNN and LSTM for text classification but getting the dimensions error for the TimeDistribution layer. The input shape of my training data is `(11800,400)` and for test data `(2951, 2)`. The code is througing the  ValueError: `TimeDistributed` Layer should be passed an `input_shape`  with at least 3 dimensions, received: [None, 400]

Here is my code snippet:

```
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 2
print(X_train.shape[0],  X_train.shape[1])
print(Y_test.shape)
model = Sequential()
# define CNN model
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features,n_outputs))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalMaxPooling1D()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
# define LSTM model
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(2))

model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')

historyCNN = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
            batch_size=32,
            epochs=10,
            validation_split=0.2)
```

Please any can help how to mitigate this dimension problem for the `TimeDistribution` layer for further transmission to `LSTM` layer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/) TimeDistributed layer reference you should provide [batch, timesteps, [data]] shape for input. In your case if you have single batch it should be (1, 11800,400)

Comment: I have solved the issue by reshaping my data in this manner (11800,400,1) using `X = X_train.reshape(len(X_train),400,1)`